# If dataframe contents are not unique; subset, combine & rename

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I've a dynamic dataframe of the following pattern:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19304, 19305, 19311, 
19311, 19312), class = "Date"), Category = c("4", 
"6", "1", "0", "3"), Units_Sold = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Raised = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Method = c("Trad", 
"Trad", "Unknown", "Trad", "Unknown"), Day = c(8, 9, 15, 15, 16)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

As you can probably see, there's two categories that have the same date. What I'd like to do is create a condition: if there are two rows with the same date, the df will be subsetted (say call it df_copy), and in that new df, one of the rows will be dropped and the contents of the "Category" column will be changed to say "Check Dataframe", and the "Method" column will be changed to say "Attention".

In answer to the question, I'd the dataframe to look something like this:

```
tibble [5 x 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Date : Date[1:5], format: "2022-11-08" "2022-11-09" "2022-11-15" "2022-11-16"
 $ Category: chr [1:5] "4" "6" "Check Dataframe" "3"
 $ Units_Sold: num [1:5] NA NA NA NA
 $ Raised: num [1:5] NA NA NA NA
 $ Method : chr [1:5] "Trade" "Trad" "Attention" "Unknown"
 $ Day: num [1:5] 8 9 15 15 16
```

If possible would it be possible to create a bool object to check against, so if there is more than 1 row with the same date, a 'checker' object will = 1?

Comment: Can you please share a sample output of how your new DF should look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dplyr, group by `Date`, add your warning flags to rows where `n() > 1`, then use `distinct()` to drop duplicate rows:

```
library(dplyr)

df_copy <- df_orig %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(
    Category = ifelse(n() > 1, "Check Dataframe", Category),
    Method = ifelse(n() > 1, "Attention", Method)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(Date, .keep_all = TRUE)

df_copy
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  Date       Category        Units_Sold Raised Method      Day
  <date>     <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1 2022-11-08 4                       NA     NA Trad          8
2 2022-11-09 6                       NA     NA Trad          9
3 2022-11-15 Check Dataframe         NA     NA Attention    15
4 2022-11-16 3                       NA     NA Unknown      16
```

Comment: This is really good. Is it possible to turn the counter into a bool object? So if there is more than 1 row with the same date, a 'checker' object will == 1?

Comment: Thanks for your continued assistance. I was more referring to creating an independent object that I can refer to in other parts of the code, if you see what I mean. I'd like to have to refer to this bool object and build other conditions based off it.

Comment: I don’t think I understand. Do you mean a function that you can pass a dataframe to to identify duplicate rows? Or a logical vector showing which rows in `df_orig` have duplicate dates? Or something else?

Comment: So what you've done already is great, I really appreciate it. But what I want to do is have the 'checker' object outside of the mutate() function so in other parts of my R code I can write conditions (e.g: if(checker == 1 ...) ) dependent on that object. At the moment, if I try to refer to 'checker', I get: object 'checker' not found. Sorry for my lack of clarity.

Comment: Or to make it a bit clearer, I'm not after a column that is either TRUE or FALSE, I'm trying to create an object that is: TRUE or FALSE if the dataframe contains more than one event on the same day.

Comment: Do you mean `checker <- function(data) length(unique(data$Date)) < nrow(data)`, which you would call like `checker(df_orig)`? If I'm still not getting it, please ask a separate question about this, including examples of what this "checker object" would look like / how it would work.

Answer (score 2):

We may group by 'Date', use an `if/else` condtion to change the values in 'Category', 'Method' columns, `slice` the first row and `ungroup`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <-  df1 %>%
    group_by(Date) %>% 
    mutate(Category = if(n() > 1) "Check Dataframe" else Category,
           Method = if(n() > 1) "Attention" else Method) %>%
    slice(n=1) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
 df2
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  Date       Category        Units_Sold Raised Method      Day
  <date>     <chr>                <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1 2022-11-08 4                       NA     NA Trad          8
2 2022-11-09 6                       NA     NA Trad          9
3 2022-11-15 Check Dataframe         NA     NA Attention    15
4 2022-11-16 3                       NA     NA Unknown      16
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, c("Category", "Method") := if(.N > 1)
    .("Check Dataframe", "Attention") else .(Category, Method), Date]
df2 <- unique(df1, by  = 'Date')
```

-output

```
> df2
         Date        Category Units_Sold Raised    Method   Day
       <Date>          <char>      <num>  <num>    <char> <num>
1: 2022-11-08               4         NA     NA      Trad     8
2: 2022-11-09               6         NA     NA      Trad     9
3: 2022-11-15 Check Dataframe         NA     NA Attention    15
4: 2022-11-16               3         NA     NA   Unknown    16
```

Comment: This is really good. Is it possible to turn the counter into a bool object? So if there is more than 1 row with the same date, a 'checker' object will == 1?